# Habilitar una caja de texto con select

Tags: php, javascript, yii

estoy intentando de habilitar una caja de texto con select con jquery

Aqui el codigo de js

```
<script>
  $('#RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_id_moneda').on('change', function (e) {
    $(this).find('option').each(function () {
      $(this).removeAttr("disabled"); 
    });
    if (option.value === '4') {
      $('#RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_otra_moneda')
        .attr('disabled', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

el selector

```
El selector

</select>
<label 
  for="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_monto_asegurado"
  class="required">Monto asegurado <span class="required">*</span>
</label>
<input
  class="span5" name="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro[monto_asegurado]"
  id="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_monto_asegurado" type="text" />
<label
  for="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_id_moneda"
  class="required">Moneda <span class="required">*</span>
</label>
<select
  name="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro[id_moneda]"
  id="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_id_moneda">
  <option value="">Seleccione la moneda</option>
  <option value="1">Bolivar</option>
  <option value="2">Dolares</option>
  <option value="3">Euros</option>
  <option value="4">Otra Moneda</option>
</select>
```

y el formulario que quiero habilitar con la opcion 4 (otra moneda)

```
 <label
   for="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_otra_moneda"
   class="required">Otra Moneda <span class="required">*</span>
 </label>
 <input
   class="span5" maxlength="30" disabled="disabled"
   name="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro[otra_moneda]"
   id="RegistroInmueble5DeSeguro_otra_moneda" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar `.prop("disabled", false)` o `.prop("disabled", true)`, en vez de `.attr()` si tienes Jquery > 1.6.

Este detalle esta aclarado en la documentación de Jquery: 
http://api.jquery.com/prop/